# How do I specify "all matching this wildcard except foo" in NFS exports file?

Tags: linux, nfs

I want to make `/share/stuff` available over NFS. The contents are public and read-only so `/etc/exports` could contain

```
/share/stuff *(ro)
```

However I want to allow an exception: `foo.mysite.com` and `bar.mysite.com` can mount this share as writable.

How do I express this in the configuration? (Using NFS isn't strictly required, any linux-friendly solution will do.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your `/etc/exports` file:

```
/share/stuff foo.mysite.com(rw) bar.mysite.com(rw) *(ro)
```